# Get document height $(document).height() using Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to get document height for various url, basically it's suppose to be the jQuery equivalent of `$(document).height()` for all pages. How should I go about this?

I am comfortable using Python and JavaScript.

Comment: strange info to take from a page :)) why do you need the height ?

Comment: I have historical scroll events and scroll position for the said urls, their max length will allow me to calculate the percentage scrolled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want browser's window size then you can use.

> **get_window_size(windowHandle='current')**
>
> Gets the width and height of the current window.
>
> Usage:    driver.get_window_size()

But that is not same as `$(document).height()`, which you have asked for, so the only way to do it is to trigger the same JavaScript command using `execute_script`.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.maximize_window()
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
print height
```

**Note:** If you want to execute the jQuery command, then you'll have to do below.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.maximize_window()
with open('jquery-1.9.1.min.js', 'r') as jquery_js: 
    jquery = jquery_js.read() #read the jquery from a file
    driver.execute_script(jquery) #active the jquery lib
    height = driver.execute_script("return $(document).height()")
    print height
```